# Cant create Ruby on Rails app on Windows - Mysql error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, installation

After installing rubyinstaller i tried creating a new mysql app with mysql and i get the below error that has to do with mysql...

Console :

```
C:\rails>rails new secret -d mysql
      create
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/assets/images/.keep
      create  app/mailers/.keep
      create  app/models/.keep
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/bundle
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.keep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.keep
      create  log
      create  log/.keep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.keep
      create  test/controllers
      create  test/controllers/.keep
      create  test/mailers
      create  test/mailers/.keep
      create  test/models
      create  test/models/.keep
      create  test/helpers
      create  test/helpers/.keep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.keep
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
         run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.1.0)
Using i18n (0.6.4)
Using minitest (4.7.5)
Using multi_json (1.7.8)
Using atomic (1.1.12)
Using thread_safe (0.1.2)
Using tzinfo (0.3.37)
Using activesupport (4.0.0)
Using builder (3.1.4)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using rack (1.5.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.2)
Using actionpack (4.0.0)
Using mime-types (1.23)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.14)
Using mail (2.5.4)
Using actionmailer (4.0.0)
Using activemodel (4.0.0)
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
Using arel (4.0.0)
Using activerecord (4.0.0)
Using bundler (1.3.5)
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
Using execjs (1.4.0)
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using thor (0.18.1)
Using railties (4.0.0)
Using coffee-rails (4.0.0)
Using hike (1.2.3)
Using jbuilder (1.5.0)
Using jquery-rails (3.0.4)
Using json (1.8.0)
Installing mysql2 (0.3.13)
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
.

    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby
        --with-mysql-dir
        --without-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
extconf.rb:37:in `<main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError
)


Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9
.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.13 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.
3.13/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.13), and Bundler cannot continue.

Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.13'` succeeds before bundling.

C:\rails>
```

Error:

```
   Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
    .

        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
    checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
    checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
    checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
    checking for rb_intern3()... yes
    *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
    necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
    details.  You may need configuration options.

    Provided configuration options:
            --with-opt-dir
            --without-opt-dir
            --with-opt-include
            --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
            --with-opt-lib
            --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
            --with-make-prog
            --without-make-prog
            --srcdir=.
            --curdir
            --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby
            --with-mysql-dir
            --without-mysql-dir
            --with-mysql-include
            --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
            --with-mysql-lib
            --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    extconf.rb:37:in `<main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError
    )


    Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9
    .1/gems/mysql2-0.3.13 for inspection.
    Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.
    3.13/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
    An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.13), and Bundler cannot continue.

    Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.13'` succeeds before bundling.

    C:\rails>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed mysql (not just the gem)?  Need more info to help you out...

Comment: Well i have XAMPP installed and work daily with PHP so even if i run the MySQL module via XAMPP and leave apache module off i still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

with doing this your issue will be solved

For some reason just specifying the mysql-dir when you install the gem doesn't pick up with other sub directories so you need to set the parameters manually.

For anyone else experiencing the same problem, I did the following:

1) Download the MySql C Connector from: [http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/][1]

use archive 32 bit for window 7 64 system
NOTE Don't download the installer, download the ARCHIVE for your OS

2) Extract the file to C:\mysql-connector

3) Then ran:

```
 gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-lib="C:\mysql-connector\lib" --with-mysql-include="C:\mysql-connector\include" --with-mysql-dir="C:\mysql-connector"'
```

after this  its working fine